# Accelerometer iphone data innovative usage

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

I am trying to isolate accelerometer not gyroscope because my device does not have it **in order to simulate distinct motions** as "**knocking a door with your iphone**" and "**drawing a cross**" in the air with your iphone and **turning a key  with your iphone as if it was to unlock the door..**

I cannot make the accelerometer accurate enough and I am using a low pass filter so this's my code for now..

any ideas?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = KUpdateInterval;

[super viewDidLoad];

}



-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
   didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

 // NSLog(@"x: %g", acceleration.x);
 // NSLog(@"y: %g", acceleration.y);
 // NSLog(@"z: %g", acceleration.z);

// Subtract the low-pass value from the current value to get a simplified high-pass     filter
accelX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
 accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
 accelZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));    
static int count = 1;


    NSLog(@"x: %g", accelX);
    NSLog(@"y: %g", accelY);
    NSLog(@"z: %g", accelZ);


if(!brokenScreenShowing){


        if (0.9 < accelZ < 0.8 && 0.03 < accelX < 0.06 ) {
        NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Layers" 
                                                              ofType:@"m4v"];
        if (moviePath) {
            NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
            moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                           initWithContentURL:movieURL];

        //          float halfHeight = [[self view] bounds].size.height / 2.0;
        //          float width = [[self view] bounds].size.width;
        //          [[self view] addSubview:[moviePlayer view]];
        //          [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, halfHeight, width, halfHeight)]; 
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
        }

        NSLog(@"first");
        count++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is your problem, but "if (0.9 < accelZ < 0.8 && 0.03 < accelX < 0.06 )" doesn't look like the right way to write that expression.

if ( ((accelZ < .9) && (accelZ > .8)) && ....